# Secure Socket with Poco

Tags: sockets, networking, tcp, tls1.2, poco-libraries

I am implementing a tcp server and client using secure sockets (Poco::Net::SecureServerSocket), I attach here the code I am using:

```
void serverClientTest()
{
    try {
        Poco::Net::initializeSSL();
        // Socket server
        Poco::Net::Context::Ptr ptrContext =
                new Poco::Net::Context(Poco::Net::Context::TLS_SERVER_USE,
                        "./cert4/myKey.pem",
                        "./cert4/myCert.pem",
                        "./cert4/myCert.pem",
                        Poco::Net::Context::VERIFY_ONCE);
        Poco::SharedPtr<Poco::Net::InvalidCertificateHandler> ptrCert = new Poco::Net::AcceptCertificateHandler(true);

        Poco::SharedPtr<Poco::Net::PrivateKeyPassphraseHandler> ptrPrivateKeyPassphraseHandler;
        ptrPrivateKeyPassphraseHandler = new Poco::Net::KeyConsoleHandler(true);

        Poco::Net::SSLManager::instance().initializeServer(ptrPrivateKeyPassphraseHandler, ptrCert, ptrContext);

        Poco::Net::SocketAddress serverAddress("0.0.0.0", 8085);
        Poco::Net::SecureServerSocket serverSecureSocket(serverAddress);
        Poco::Net::TCPServer srv(new Poco::Net::TCPServerConnectionFactoryImpl<EchoConnection>(), serverSecureSocket);
        srv.start();

        Poco::Net::Context::Ptr ptrContext2 =
                new Poco::Net::Context(Poco::Net::Context::TLS_CLIENT_USE,
                        "./cert4/myKey.pem",
                        "./cert4/myCert.pem",
                        "./cert4/myCert.pem",
                        Poco::Net::Context::VERIFY_ONCE);

        Poco::SharedPtr<Poco::Net::InvalidCertificateHandler> ptrCert2 = new Poco::Net::AcceptCertificateHandler(true);

        Poco::SharedPtr<Poco::Net::PrivateKeyPassphraseHandler>ptrPrivateKeyPassphraseHandler2(new Poco::Net::KeyConsoleHandler(false));

        Poco::Net::SSLManager::instance().initializeClient(ptrPrivateKeyPassphraseHandler2, ptrCert2, ptrContext2);

        Poco::Net::SocketAddress sa("127.0.0.1", 8085);
        Poco::Net::SecureStreamSocket ss1(sa);
        std::string data("TEST  TEST");
        int retSend = ss1.sendBytes(data.data(), (int) data.size());
        if (retSend>0)
        {
            std::cout << "buffer -> : " << data.data() << std::endl;
            char buffer[1024];
            memset(buffer, '\0', 1024);
            int retRecv = ss1.receiveBytes(buffer, sizeof(buffer));
            if (retRecv > 0)
            {
                std::cout << "buffer <- : " << buffer << std::endl;
            }
            else
            {
                std::cout << "ERROR: recv " << retRecv << std::endl;
            }
        }
        ss1.close();
    }
    catch (Poco::Exception& ex)
    {
        std::cout << "!!  EXCEPTION "<< ex.displayText() << std::endl;
    }
}
//[....]
class EchoConnection: public Poco::Net::TCPServerConnection
{
public:
   EchoConnection(const Poco::Net::StreamSocket& s): Poco::Net::TCPServerConnection(s){}

   void run()
   {
       Poco::Net::StreamSocket& ss = socket();
       std::cout << "connection from client: " << ss.address() << std::endl;
       try
       {
            // ...
       }
       catch (Poco::Exception& exc)
       {
           std::cerr << "--------------- EchoConnection: " << exc.displayText() << std::endl;
       }
   }
};
```

I would like the server to close the connection if the client certificate is not known to the server, but it happens
which, even with the context:

```
    Poco::Net::Context::Ptr ptrContext2 =
            new Poco::Net::Context(Poco::Net::Context::TLS_CLIENT_USE,
                    "",
                    "",
                    "./cert4/myCert.pem",
                    Poco::Net::Context::VERIFY_ONCE);
```

Thanks to anyone who can help me out.

Answer (score 0):

```
void serverClientTest()
{
try {
    Poco::Net::initializeSSL();
    // Socket server
    Poco::Net::Context::Ptr ptrContext =
            new Poco::Net::Context(Poco::Net::Context::SERVER_USE,
                    "./server.key",
                    "./server.crt",
                    "./ca.pem",
                    Poco::Net::Context::VERIFY_STRICT,
                    9,
                    false,
                    "ALL:!ADH:!LOW:!EXP:!MD5:@STRENGTH");

    Poco::SharedPtr<Poco::Net::InvalidCertificateHandler> ptrCert = new Poco::Net::AcceptCertificateHandler(true);

    Poco::SharedPtr<Poco::Net::PrivateKeyPassphraseHandler> ptrPrivateKeyPassphraseHandler;
    ptrPrivateKeyPassphraseHandler = new Poco::Net::KeyConsoleHandler(true);

    Poco::Net::SSLManager::instance().initializeServer(ptrPrivateKeyPassphraseHandler, ptrCert, ptrContext);

    Poco::Net::SocketAddress serverAddress("0.0.0.0", 8085);
    Poco::Net::SecureServerSocket serverSecureSocket(serverAddress);
    Poco::Net::TCPServer srv(new Poco::Net::TCPServerConnectionFactoryImpl<EchoConnection>(), serverSecureSocket);
    srv.start();

    Poco::Net::Context::Ptr ptrContext2 =
            new Poco::Net::Context(Poco::Net::Context::CLIENT_USE,
                    "./client.key",
                    "./client.crt",
                    "./ca.pem",
                    Poco::Net::Context::VERIFY_STRICT,
                    9,
                    true,
                    "ALL:!ADH:!LOW:!EXP:!MD5:@STRENGTH");

    Poco::SharedPtr<Poco::Net::InvalidCertificateHandler> ptrCert2 = new Poco::Net::AcceptCertificateHandler(true);

    Poco::SharedPtr<Poco::Net::PrivateKeyPassphraseHandler>ptrPrivateKeyPassphraseHandler2(new Poco::Net::KeyConsoleHandler(false));

    Poco::Net::SSLManager::instance().initializeClient(ptrPrivateKeyPassphraseHandler2, ptrCert2, ptrContext2);

    Poco::Net::SocketAddress sa("127.0.0.1", 8085);
    Poco::Net::SecureStreamSocket ss1(sa);
    std::string data("TEST");
    int retSend = ss1.sendBytes(data.data(), (int) data.size());
    if (retSend>0)
    {
        char buffer[1024];
        memset(buffer, '\0', 1024);
        int retRecv = ss1.receiveBytes(buffer, sizeof(buffer));
        if (retRecv > 0)
        {
            std::cout << "buffer <-: " << buffer << std::endl;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "ERROR: " << retRecv << std::endl;
        }
    }
    ss1.close();
}
catch (Poco::Exception& ex)
{
    std::cout << ex.displayText() << std::endl;
}
```

}